# Microsoft Expression Studio 4 Ultimate license problem

Tags: installation, license, microsoft-expression

I have installed a volume licensed version of Expression Studio 4 Ultimate.
When I contacted support, I was told that a product key is not required for volume license version.

But after I installing it, I get the following error message:

> A licensing error has occurred. Restart your Expression program and try again. If you continue to receive this error message, reinstall your Expression program to make sure that the license installs correctly.

[image]

As a side note, I used to have full version of Blend 3 and Blend 4 Beta installed side by side.

Comment: Nothing worked so i reinstalled my windows 7 - Now it works.

Comment: I have expression studio 4 on my computer and indeed you don't even need a serial number to install it. However, it doesn't mean piracy protection is not included. Maybe it's sharing the same anti-piracy infrastructure (Software Licensing and Protection Services) with your OS. Check if the relevant service (Software Protection) is running.

Comment: Voted to close as too localized, as answers to this question cannot be verified anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem without reinstall thw Win 7.

Install the: http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/D/8/FD88D81D-52B5-486A-A53F-CCDB485D5258/Web_Trial_en.exe

In my case is solved